pyodbc.connect() fails on Ubuntu(WSL2), but done on Windows
I use the following code to connect SQL Server.
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=mydb;UID=user;PWD=pass')

It works on Jupter Notebook based it's env on Windows.
But with with same SQL Server,  when it comes to another Jupter Notebook based it's env on WSL2(Ubuntu)，it returns error:

('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

How to fix it?
When executing the command in WSL2, I got following error (172.27.224.1 is the Windows Sql Server IP):
(rapids-24.02) user@DESKTOP:~$ sqlcmd -S 172.27.224.1 -U user -P pass


Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SSL Provider: [error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.

When executing the commands in WSL2, it both returns seccess:
nc -zv 172.27.224.1 1433


Connection to 172.27.224.1 1433 port [tcp/ms-sql-s] succeeded!

telnet 172.27.224.1 1433


Trying 172.27.224.1...
Connected to 172.27.224.1.
Escape character is '^]'.


SSL routines::unsupported protocol. The ODBC drivers on Linux (and so, under WSL) use OpenSSL which expects modern servers to be using TLS 1.2 (or better) encryption protocols. What's the output of SELECT @@VERSION when executed on your SQL Server instance? SQL Server 2016 and later have TLS 1.2 support out-of-the-box, but if you're on SQL Server 2008 through 2014 you need to install Service Packs and/or Cumulative Updates. Ref: TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server

I too have the same issue, did you find a solution. I am trying to connect to MSSQL server 2014.
